# using ?? operator for string null or empty and DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, string

I  want the following logic to be a one liner ,

```
string CastString(String str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
       return DBNull.Value.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

what I tried is

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? DBNull.Value : str
```

is there a way to use the ?? operator for this , what I tried is

```
return str ?? DBNull.Value
```

but this does not work

Comment: `??` checks for null, but in your original code you are also checking for an empty string.  So a ternary operator is ideal here.

Comment: what does it do with `sql-server` tag?

Comment: Why do you bother with `DBNull.Value.ToString()` it is just going to return `String.Empty`, if you where returning a `object` instead of a `string` it would make sense to do `return DBNull.Value;` but doing `return DBNull.Value.ToString();` is pointless.

Comment: "I want the following logic to be a one liner" Well, calling the method you already have: CastString(someValue) is just one line and you can declare it public and static which is probably going to be more handy. What else do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator will make it a one-liner

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are are missing ToString(), but still it will not check Empty string.

```
return str ?? DBNull.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't think that checks for when the string is empty

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my remark, I just corrected the error in his code